# Facebook remembers previous image when trying to share page

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-5, metadata

This is driving me mental! I have page which has a share button on it, for arguments sake I have hard coded the image name and title in the controller as shown here

```
 public ActionResult ThankYou()
    {
        var model = new LabCombination
        {
            ImageCombination = "danone_ultimate_coconut_vanilla.png",
            ImageTitle = "danone_ultimate_coconut_vanilla"
        };

        return View(model);
    }
```

In my view I do this

```
  <meta property="og:title" content="Check out the flavour I just made! @Model.ImageTitle" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="Check out the flavour I have just created!" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://danone.staging-eurorscg.com.au/Content/Images/FlavourLab/CombinationSmall/@Model.ImageCombination" />
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://danone.staging-eurorscg.com.au/thank-you" />
```

which renders as follows

```
 <meta property="og:title" content="Check out the flavour I just made! danone_ultimate_coconut_vanilla" />
 <meta property="og:description" content="Check out the flavour I have just created!" />
 <meta property="og:image" content="http://danone.staging-eurorscg.com.au/Content/Images/FlavourLab/CombinationSmall/danone_ultimate_coconut_vanilla.png" />
 <meta property="og:url" content="http://danone.staging-eurorscg.com.au/thank-you" />
```

When I do the facebook scraper I see this 
[image]

yet when I go to the page a press share I see this

[image]

Why is facebook not refreshing! I have cleared the cache in my browser!

You can scrap the page here

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

with the following url

http://danone.staging-eurorscg.com.au/thank-you

Any help would be appreciated

** Update ** As I set the mete data dynamically, it caches the original information as shown here, what you see in the middle of the screen i.e the image should be also displayed in the shared dialog

[image]

My Meta data looks like this

```
 <meta property="og:title" content="Check out the flavour I just made! Strawberry &amp; Honey" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Check out the flavour I have just created!" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://danone.staging-eurorscg.com.au/Content/Images/FlavourLab/CombinationSmall/danone_ultimate_strawberry_honey.png" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://danone.staging-eurorscg.com.au/thank-you" />
```

As you can see it has all the correct meta data.

Answer (score 0):

That is because your share button is trying to share the url http://danone.staging-eurorscg.com.au/flavour-lab and not http://danone.staging-eurorscg.com.au/thank-you

Comment: that's the page I want to share, so when the user shares it on FB I don't want the user to click it and be taken to the thank-you page, I want them to go to the falvour lab page

Comment: Ok I have it working, but facebook is still caching the previous content as shown in my update, you can see I have selected strawberries and honey, yet when shared it displays coconut, even my meta data is correct....

Comment: Yes Facebook caches the title. So don't change it every second.

Comment: The title needs to change see my question regarding clearing meta data http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28732397/clear-facebook-meta-data-instantly as I need it to clear

Answer (score 0):

Add the following og meta tag, with the current epoch time:

```
<meta property="og:updated_time" content="1431713584" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can force Facebook to update it's cache using debugger tool. It used to be called url linter.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/